# Understanding SimpleRNN process

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have created the following SimpleRNN using Keras:

```
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
tr_X, ts_X, tr_y, ts_y = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=.8)
batch_size = 1000

print('RNN model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(64, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

print('Training...')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print (model.summary())
print ('\n')

model.fit(tr_X, tr_y,
          batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1,
          shuffle=True, validation_data=(ts_X, ts_y))
```

For the model summary, I get the following:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_1 (SimpleRNN)     (1000, 64)                4224      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (1000, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 4,289
Trainable params: 4,289
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Given that I have a dataset of 10,000 samples and 64 features. My goal is to generate a classification model by training it using this dataset (class labels are binary 0 and 1). Now, I am trying to understand what is going on here. As seen in 'Output Shape' column, the simple_rnn_1 has (1000, 64). I interpret it as `1000` rows (which is the batch) and `64` features. Assuming the code above is logically correct, my questions is:

1. How does RNN handle this matrix (i.e., (1000,64))? Does it input
   each column something like this figure?

[image]

2. Should SimpleRNN() `units` always be equal to the number of features?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. In the code, you defined batch_input_shape to be with shape: (batch_size, X.shape[1], 1)
   which means that you will insert to the RNN, batch_size examples, each example contains X.shape[1] **time-stamps** (number of pink boxes in your image) and each time-stamp is shape 1 (scalar).
   So yes, input shape of (1000,64,1) will be exactly like you said - each column will be input to the RNN.
2. No! units will be your output dim. Usually more units means more complex network (just like in regular neural network) -> more parameters to learn.
   Units will be the shape of the RNN's internal state.
   (So, in your example, if you declare units=2000 your output will be (1000,2000).)